# Which function of $n$ has higher growth rate between $f(n)=(\log n)^{100}$ and $g(n)= n^{0.000001}$ as $n$ approaches infinity?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, asymptotics, limits-without-lhopital

I am really confused.
I don't know how to start solving these questions. Generally I divide by $n$, then I solve the question. But in these case, neither am I able to apply L'Hôpital's rule nor can I divide by $n$. I need to find which of the two has higher growth rate. Can any relation between them be established?

Comment: Are you taking some ratio between $f(n)$ and $g(n)$? Cause both functions go to infinity on their own?

Comment: @QC_QAOA hii, I re-edited the question. Now i think it will be clear

Comment: You should put the question into the main body not just into the title.

Comment: Note that $$
\frac{{f(n)}}{{g(n)}} = \left( {\frac{{\log n}}{{n^{0.00000001} }}} \right)^{100} 
$$ and then use L'Hôpital's rule to show $$
\frac{{\log n}}{{n^{0.00000001} }} \to 0.
$$